# SharePoint Online on a subdomain

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've just setup SharePoint Online and instead of using default domain

> company.sharepoint.com

I would like to use a subdomain from our company website:

> intranet.company.com

I looked at adding a new domain in the SharePoint Online Admin centre as a possible solution for this however as we already have a company website running on the main domain I didn't feel very comfortable experimenting. It seemed to me that by adding the TXT or MX records they were suggesting I would risk redirecting all traffic from the domain.

We are purely using SharePoint Online and have no other infrastructure around this at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After you add a custom domain to Office 365, you might want to change the name for your team site from, for example, contoso.sharepoint.com to fourthcoffee.sharepoint.com. But unfortunately, it isn’t possible to simply change the name or use a custom domain name for a team site because of how the architecture works for Office 365 team sites.
>
> If you must change the name of a team site, you will need to create a new Office 365 account and use the name that you want to use for the onmicrosoft.com domain as part of sign up. Other steps you may need to take include removing your custom domain from the original account (the one with the team site name that you didn't want) and moving any email, files, or other data you may have set up with that account to the new one.
>
> **Applies To**: Office 365 Small Business Admin, SharePoint Online, Office 365 Admin

Reference: [Can't rename team site on Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Can-t-rename-team-site-on-Office-365-576325ad-8c40-4fe8-8a63-68c3b7d536cf?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)

Another “solution” would be to NOT have your custom domain in Office 365, but to keep it at your DNS hosting provider. With that you can create websites that uses `iframe` for the entire team site company.sharepoint.com and that doesn’t reveal the real URL. That could work, but I wouldn’t recommend this solution since you’re facing a lot of unwanted DNS maintenance which could break the entire DNS structure. If that happens, you have a potential risk to be offline for hours (or even days). The site would still function, but the DNS iframe would fail.

```
DNS URL                iframed to                           Site type
company.com            www.company-public.sharepoint.com    Public Website
intranet.company.com   company.sharepoint.com               Team Site
```